# C# datagridview combobox column datasource from list/dictionary/datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I've got a datatable and one column is an integer ID foreign key to another database table.

I've got a datagridview and i'd like to use a combobox column to allow user to change value. But instead of using the integers, it would be great to use the names.

I've tried creating a simple struct with public members int ID and string Name; a dictionary and looked into enums (however values not known at compile time) but not got anything to work yet.

I was able to populate the combobox with struct values, but not able to programmatically set the selected item/index; ie, if ID "5" is in the datatable, set the combo box selected item to the struct that has an ID of 5.

So to be clear i'm wanting:

```
gridview datasource's fk ID's 
1
2
3

Foreign Key table:

ID   Name 
1    Name 1
2    Name 2
3    Name 3
```

Datagridviewcombobox column should be loaded with three items; should display as "Name 1, Name 2, Name 3". Based on the gridview datasource's FK id, the selected item for each should match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the [`DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource.aspx) property, and then use the [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.valuemember.aspx) and [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaymember.aspx) properties to determine what is shown in the `ComboBox`.  Easiest is probably to load your FK values into `DataTable` and use that as the data source.  For your example:

```
// assuming your DataGridViewComboBox column is fkCol
// and your fk values are in a DataTable called fkTable
fkCol.DataSource = fkTable;
fkCol.ValueMember = "ID";
fkCol.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I am not sure how you are binding your `DataGridView` to your initial `DataTable`, but you can associate the `DataGridViewComboBox` column with a specific column in your original `DataTable` using [`DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx):

```
fkCol.DataPropertyName = "ColumnName";
```

Comment: Thanks heas ! 1/2 a day of searching and all i needed was 2 more lines of code - DOH! This is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
    DataTable movies = dal.GetMovies();

    gvMovies.DataSource = movies;
    gvMovies.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    gvMovies.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;

    //Create the new combobox column and set it's DataSource to a DataTable
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    col.DataSource = dal.GetMovieTypes(); ; 
    col.ValueMember = "MovieTypeID";
    col.DisplayMember = "MovieType";
    col.DataPropertyName = "MovieTypeID";

    //Add your new combobox column to the gridview
    gvMovies.Columns.Add(col);
```